# K&R c book 5-9 exercise

Tags: c, pointers

This example requires to use pointer instead of index to implement the functions, I fully understand how to write it when I saw some solutions, but I change a little bit, which is far different from others, my version is not complicated, I just try to use pointer anywhere I can:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int day_of_year(int, int, int);
void month_day(int, int, int *, int *);
static char (*daytab)[13] = {
        {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31},
        {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
};
int main(){
    int day = day_of_year(2000,6,23);
    printf("%d\n", day);
    int pmonth[1];
    int pday[1];
    month_day(2000, 175, pmonth, pday);
    printf("%d,%d\n", *pmonth, *pday);
    return 0;
}
/* day of the year:set day of the year from month & day  */
int day_of_year(int year, int month, int day){
    int i, leap;
    leap = year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0;
    char *arr = daytab;
    if (leap == 1)
        arr += 13;
    for (i = 1;  i < month; i++){
        day = day + (*++arr);
    }
    return day;
}
/* month_day: set month and day from the day of year  */
void month_day(int year, int day_year, int *pmonth, int *pday){
    int i, leap;
    leap = year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0;
    char *arr = daytab;
    if (leap)
        arr += 13;
    for (i = 1; day_year > *++arr; i++)
        day_year -= *arr;
    *pmonth = i;
    *pday = day_year;
}
```

but when I compile, it gives me a lot of warning:

```
date_convert.c:6:38: note: (near initialization for ‘daytab’)
date_convert.c:6:2: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
  {0,31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
  ^
date_convert.c:6:2: note: (near initialization for ‘daytab’)
date_convert.c: In function ‘day_of_year’:
date_convert.c:21:17: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     char *arr = daytab;
                 ^~~~~~
date_convert.c: In function ‘month_day’:
date_convert.c:33:17: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     char *arr = daytab;
                 ^~~~~~
```

The incompitability is that the type is different, but when dereferencing it, It should return the same type value which is just enough, the bad effect is that it will run into segmentation fault.... So any advice to fix the problem? really appreciate it!

Comment: It looks like you've tried to declare `daytab` as an array of `[13]char`, but you've declared it a pointer to `[13]char`. The compiler is complaining because you've tried to initialize a pointer with `{0, 31, 29, ...}`. Given your later code, perhaps you want `char daytab[26] = {...}` (with {} containing the 26 values). I'd probably write `const int month_len_nonleap[13] = {...}` and `const int month_len_leap[13] = {...}` and choose the  appropriate one (rather than use a single array and offset into it like you're currently doing).

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff805a9925e10e69